# Using GrantAccessRequest to give READ rights

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, security-roles

I want to remove READ rights from a security role on systemuser entity and execute a plugin on each new systemuser creation – it will grant READ to the particular user so that only his/her systemuser record is visible to them. 
The plugin has to run very last in the chain asynchronously.

In my plugin I use following code to assign read rights to user,

```
                    EntityReference systemUser = PostImage.ToEntityReference();
                    GrantAccessRequest grantRequest = new GrantAccessRequest()
                    {
                        Target = systemUser,
                        PrincipalAccess = new PrincipalAccess()
                        {
                            Principal = systemUser,
                            AccessMask = AccessRights.ReadAccess 
                        }
                    };

                    GrantAccessResponse grantResponse =
                        (GrantAccessResponse)XrmServiceContext.Execute(grantRequest);
```

But when I create a new user and logged in using that credentials, this doesn't seem to make any change. All the systemuser records are visible!What am I doing wrong? Currently systemuser has read permisson set to 'organization' in crm security roles.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this in a plugin or any other kind of code. All users are granted explicit shares to their own user record and user settings via rows in the PrincipalObjectAccess ('POA') table.